# Effective method to bin variables in Python

Tags: python, pandas

All,

I am new to python and trying to categorize the data into bins.

Assume, I have 2 columns Age and Purchase. Age is a continuous variable and Purchase is a binary variable (1-Yes, 0-No). I want to categorize age into bins and see the total no of purchases in each bin.

I have written the following code but I sincerely believe there is much more effective method to do that. Please check the following and suggest new methods or enhancements.

Code:

```
bins = [15, 30, 40, 50, 60, np.inf]

names = ['15-30', '30-40', '40-50', '50-60', '60+']

dataset['AgeRange'] = pd.cut(dataset['Age'], bins, labels=names)

df = [ dataset[dataset.AgeRange == '15-30'].Purchased.sum(), 
   dataset[dataset.AgeRange == '30-40'].Purchased.sum(),
   dataset[dataset.AgeRange == '40-50'].Purchased.sum(),
   dataset[dataset.AgeRange == '50-60'].Purchased.sum() ]
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Aren't you basically trying to compute a histogram? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Comment: Yes. A 2dHistogram. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Also Consider using list comprehension to create your labels:

```
bins = [15, 30, 40, 50, 60, np.inf]
labels = [f'{i}+' if j==np.inf else f'{i}-{j}' for i, j in zip(bins, bins[1:])]

dataset['AgeRange'] = pd.cut(dataset['Age'], bins, labels)
dataset.groupby('AgeRange')['Purchased'].sum()
```